# import large excel file in laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, import, queue, laravel-excel

I have a big excel file. I want to check it in the database before uploading it.
for example customers excel file

**name - surname - phone**

john - smith - 444

marta - pack - 555

patrick - blackmore - 666

before adding this data to the database, one by one, if there is a record of the customer phone number, print it to the screen, if not, add it to the database. how can I do this the fastest. laravel queue? by running python with shell exec? and I want to continue using the system while this is running in the background.

thank you in advance for your help

i dont know, what can i do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.